# svnsync timeout after 10 minutes

Tags: svn, timeout, svnsync

I have two Subversion repositories, a primary one and a secondary one.
I want to setup `svnsync` to mirror all the commits on the primary repository to the secondary.

But after the set up with svnsync init, when I launch `svnsync synchronize` to populate the secondary repo with the data already in the primary one, I get a timeout error after 10 minutes:

```
svnsync synchronize http://secondary-repo --username=xxx --password=xxx
svnsync: E175012: Connection timed out
```

The commits are quite big, some gigabytes.
I tried to increase the timeout in the apache configuration, but nothing changed.

Is there any other configuration value I can tweak to have the commit complete without timeout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Subversion client has a timeout value as well.  Look for a property called "http-timeout" in the config file named "[servers](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers)".

Answer (score 1):

In `%appdata%\subversion\servers`, there are 2 sections, `[groups]` and `[global]`. I configured mine under `[global]`:

> [global]
> #Adjust XX (in seconds)
> http-timeout = XX

Note: To make the setting effective, just close the TortoiseSVN window(s).

P.S The *default* timeout is 10mins.

Comment: 10 months later, i forget what i did and found my own answer :D