# TORTOISE download svn: E175012: Connection timed out and locked

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

this is my first time to use SVN.( I think the problem is SVN ) those are the environment what I use:

i want make a subversion of this repo

svn checkout https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/
trunk/lib/win64_vc14  lib/win64_vc14

i follow this, but no have explanaions of errors

https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Windows

```
svn checkout https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/lib/win64_vc14  lib/win64_vc14
```

I expected it to be completely downloaded and continue with the second download step

```
A    lib\win64_vc14\opencollada\lib\opencollada\OpenCOLLADABaseUtils.lib                                            svn: E175012: Connection timed out                                                                                  PS C:\Users\Courtney\Downloads\Git-Repositorys\Git-Blender> C:\Users\Courtney\Downloads\Git-Repositorys\Git-Blender>
```

I tried one more time

```
PS C:\Users\Courtney\Downloads\Git-Repositorys\Git-Blender> svn checkout https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/lib/win64_vc14  lib/win64_vc14                                                                                svn: E155004: Run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)                               svn: E155004: Working copy 'C:\Users\Courtney\Downloads\Git-Repositorys\Git-Blender\lib\win64_vc14' locked.         svn: E155004: 'C:\Users\Courtney\Downloads\Git-Repositorys\Git-Blender\lib\win64_vc14' is already locked.           PS C:\Users\Courtney\Downloads\Git-Repositorys\Git-Blender> svn checkout https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/lib/win64_vc14  lib/win64_vc14
```

but the problem seems to get worse because now this is blocked

[windows power shell code lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzugV.png)

Comment: Try with git repo using tortoise git or bash. Then run .bat over windows

Comment: @Mate which git tortoise, I'm confused, they made me install 2 different ones and in the end I just had to install one that is the one they use, so now I'm confused which one is what each one does, I'd prefer to do it with GIT, but it does not say how https://imgur.com/z773rkv

Comment: do not even use tortoise, just use windows shell and xterm of linux or git but do not tortoise

Comment: in blender org they do not answer you and in blender stack exchange, they are pretty nefarious do not want you to ask questions about this, and also there are many stalkers who are administrators, and I am already annoyed by them

Comment: https://imgur.com/2bOdBCv tortoisgit say this and send me an a document

Answer (score 6):

Check your [Runtime Configuration Area](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html), especially [the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10617826/6309) (`%appdata%\subversion\servers`)

There should be a [`http-timeout` line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33661793/6309).
Try and set it to 0.

> This specifies the amount of time, in seconds, to wait for a server response.
>
> If you experience problems with a slow network connection causing Subversion operations to time out, you should increase the value of this option.
>
> In Subversion 1.8 (or older versions employing the Serf-based HTTP provider), use the value 0 to disable the timeout altogether.

Comment: This is the first time I use SVN, I do not even know what we are talking about, it looks more complex and quite slow, and I do not have much time to read such a large document due to overwork

Comment: @BlenderBlackened Simply go to `%appdata%\subversion\config` and check if there is a file with `http-timeout` in it. Set it to 0 and try again your svn clone.

Comment: I didn't really do it because after doing what I posted as an answer, I did not have any more problems

Comment: although I did not have any problems, I applied the solution, although I do not persist a change, I prefer to apply it so that in future downloads of svn I will not cause problems

Comment: @VonC, the `http-timeout` is a `%appdata%\subversion\server` setting under the `[global]` section. Putting it in the `config` file is useless.

Comment: @DavorJosipovic Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: %appdata%\subversion\servers (with an s in the server filename)

Comment: @JAY Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Youhave timeout settings both on the server side (svn/Apache httpd server) and the client side. Adding a http-timeout in the "global" section of the file %appdata%\subversion\servers can indeed solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Right Mouse Button in the Locked Folder

1. List item
2. Select TORTOISESVN
3. Select CLEANUP
4. Clean up dialog would appear automatically
5. Select Clean up working copy status, Break locks, Fix time stamps,
   Vacuum pristine copies, Refresh shell overlays, Include externals
6. Press OK

[SOLVED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbqjJ.png)

[full download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PFMp.png)

Comment: this works fine for me now it's downloading again and I did not have to delete anything else, see the screenshot please: https://imgur.com/NMugSpv